# How to align pointers when dealing with multiple-inheritance?

Tags: c++, pointers, multiple-inheritance, vtable, memory-alignment

Say we have a concrete class A, and an abstract class B.

Consider a concrete C, that inherits from both A and B, and implements B:

```
class C : public A, public B  
{  
/* implementation of B and specific stuff that belongs to C */  
};
```

Now I define a function which signature is `void foo(B* b);`

This is my code, I can assume that every pointers to B are both A and B.
In foo's definition, how to get a pointer to A?
A nasty but working trick is to align back pointers like so:

```
void foo(B* b)  
{  
    A* a = reinterpret_cast<A*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(b) - sizeof(A));
    // now I can use all the stuff from A  
}
```

Keep in mind that C does not have a super type and actually, there are many classes akin to C which only are A and B. Feel free to question both my logic and this sample of design as well but the question is only concerning pointers alignment.

Comment: The result of any attempt to get an `A` from a `B` is almost certainly *undefined*.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: It's perfectly defined in this case since I'm sure I get a pointer to B from an instance of C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
void foo(B* b)  
{  
    //A* a = reinterpret_cast<A*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(b) - sizeof(A)); // undefined behaviour!!!!
    A* a = dynamic_cast<A*>(b);
    if (a)
    {
       // now I can use all the stuff from A  
    }
    else
    {
       // that was something else, not descended from A
    }
}
```

Forgot to say: in order to make work dynamic cast both A and B should have virtual function(s) or at least virtual destructors.  Otherwise there is no legal way to do that type conversion.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: I don't think you are familiar to C++ enough to make such conclusions.

Comment: @Jurlie: Then try compiling this.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth : This compiles and works fine as long as both `A` and `B` are polymorphic (i.e., have a vtable). I'm not sure what your contention is...

Comment: I take that back, it will compile, in certain circumstances.  As @ildjarn says, `B` needs to be polymorphic for this to compile.

Comment: @Jurlie : Any virtual function will do, it doesn't need to be the destructor. (Of course, the destructors being virtual in this case is *probably* a good idea anyway...)

Comment: Oli Charlesworth: I forgot to notice that that way requires classes to be polimorphic. So you're right.

Comment: @Jurlie: We were both right, for different reasons!  Anyway, -1 removed.

Comment: I don't know why I was sure that dynamic_cast would produce a compile error since A and B are unrelated types except through C. Thanks Jurlie!

Comment: @mister why : Keep in mind that while this approach may work, it's downright silly. I'd strongly consider the approach suggested by sharptooth.

Comment: @Jurlie: minor point, but since `a` is only safely usable if not null, I would consider using this form here `if (A* a = dynamic_cast...)` this way it's inaccessible in case it's null, which prevents silly mistakes.

Comment: @Matthieu M Interesting trick. Perhaps compiler will produce warning "assignment within conditional expression" on it.

Comment: @Jurlie: It will not here because *the type* (`A*`, or `auto` these days) in front of the variable name makes it unambiguous. If the variable were declared before, and you just wrote `if (a = ...)` then the compiler would emit a warning.

Answer (score 2):

Having a huge set of unrelated classes that both derive from `A` and `B` is a very strange design. If there's something that makes `A` and `B` always be "used together" you could either *merge* them or *introduce a shim class* that only derives from them and then only derive from that class:

```
class Shim : A, B {};

class DerivedX : Shim {};
```

and in the latter case you just use `static_cast` to first downcast from `A` or `B` to  `Shim*` and then C++ it will implicitly convert the `Shim*` pointer to the other class.

Comment: I got you, but I didn't provide the whole design. Actually B is not always the same abstract class. It can be either an abstract B1 or an abstract B2 that both inherits from B. When I am in foo, I don't know the kind of C I have. A nice design based on templates would force me to use the [CRTP idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) which is definitely not convenient for peculiar reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the functionality of both class A and Class B in your function then you should modify the function to receive C pointers:

```
void foo(C* c);
```

And in general you are wrong with you assumption that "every B is an A as well". You could create classes derived from you B interface and not derived from Class A, that's why the compiler won't know that in your specific case "every B is an A".

Comment: Well, based on your comment to the previous post I think that your foo function should be examined because it may be two different functions (one is working with descendants of B and the other is working with the class A) and they should be called one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on sharptooth's answer (and entering it as an answer, because I can't get formatted code into a comment), you can still use the shim:

```
class Shim : public virtual A, public virtual B {};
```

Then:

```
class Derived1 : public Shim, public virtual A, public virtual B1
{
};

class Derived2 : public Shim, public virtual A, public virtual B2
{
};
```

`B1` and `B2` must derive virtually from `B`.

But I suspect that if you always need to implement both `A` and
`B`, you should create a single interface with both, either by
inheriting, or coalising both into a single class; your `B1` and
`B2` would inherit from that.  (The solution with
`dynamic_cast`, of course, is for the case where the derived
class of `B` may or may not also derived from `A`.)